# Pressing the ajax button again after the first time gives a strange error

Tags: javascript, ajax

Basically when I press the button the first time ajax loads perfectly but when I press that same ajax button again it gives me this error

*(index):17 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
    at sendAJAX (http://etc.../:17:5)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://etc.../:29:40)*

I have found articles about this but they are confusing to a point where I don't know how to integrate those solutions to my script, to get it to work with my script so I need a code example solution based on my exact script not based on some one else's script so I can

better understand this based on my script. I mainly want to know how can I keep calling the same ajax request regardless how many times I press that same button with out errors.

Code example

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<title>AJAX with JavaScript</title>
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
};
xhr.open('GET', 'sidebar.html');
function sendAJAX() {
xhr.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container centered">
<div class="grid-100">
<div class="contained">
<div class="grid-100">
<div class="heading">
<h1>Bring on the AJAX</h1>
<button id="load" onclick="sendAJAX()">Bring it!</button>
</div>
<ul id="ajax">

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<section>
<h2>Welcome to the wonderful world of AJAX</h2>
<p>This content provided to you dynamically by the XMLHTTP Request Object</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your `xhr` element only once, so if `sendAJAX` is called a second time, then `send` is called on an `XMLHttpRequest` that was already send.

After `send` is called the state of the `xhr` obeject is not *opened*  anymore and because of that you get the error message.

You can solve the problem by creating new `XMLHttpRequest` for each `sendAJAX` call.

```
function sendAJAX() {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', 'sidebar.html');
  xhr.send();
}
```

Or by only moving `open` into the `sendAJAX`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }
};

function sendAJAX() {

  xhr.open('GET', 'sidebar.html');
  xhr.send();
}
```

[XMLHttpRequest.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)

> **Note:** Calling open for an already active request (one for which open() has already been called) is the equivalent of calling abort().

Comment: Thank you so much @t.niese I been trying to find a solution based on my script for a long long time you made my day thanks :-)